# AWS IAM authorization inside a lambda function in nodejs

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, amazon-iam

I have an API protected by IAM authorization, which a resource policy that allows IAM user `integ-user` to invoke the API.

Now I want to write a lambda function to invoke the same API. Given that I have access to the IAM access key and secret (either by environment variables or AWS Secret Manager), how do I IAM-authorize the user so it can invoke the API successfully?

Sample code that is used to invoke the same API (without IAM authorization):

```
var https = require('https');

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    const options = {
        host: process.env.VPCE_DNS_NAME,
        port: 443,
        path: "/status",
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
          'Host':process.env.API_GW_ENDPOINT
        }
      };

    https.request(options, (res) => {
      let data = '';
      res.on('data', (d) => {
       data += d;
        process.stdout.write(d);
      });
      res.on('end', () => {
         callback(null, JSON.parse(data));
      });
    }).on('error', (e) => {
      callback(null, e);
    }).end();
};
```

Comment: You'll need to sign your request by adding a number of headers containing the required values for the AWS signing v4 process. This is hard to do by hand. Take a look at https://github.com/yugasun/aws4-sign - that has a couple of good examples based on key/secret logins.

Answer (score 2):

We need to build regular nodejs request options with three additional parameters

`service: "execute-api"` for Api Gateway

`region: "us-east-1"` AWS Region.

`body: postData` , typically we pass body  `req.write`, we also need it in options because it is needed for signing.

and finally the `aws4.sign(...)` is passed to `request`.

All `.sign` method does is adds 4 additional headers `X-Amz-Content-Sha256`, `X-Amz-Security-Token`, `X-Amz-Date` and `Authorization`

```
var aws4 = require("aws4");
var https = require("https");

const requestBody = { name: "test" };
var postData = JSON.stringify(requestBody);

var options = {
  method: "GET",
  hostname: "abcdefgh.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com",
  path: "/status",
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
  },
  service: "execute-api",
  region: "us-east-1",
  body: postData,
  maxRedirects: 20,
};

const signedRequest = aws4.sign(options, {
  secretAccessKey: "abcadefghijknlmnopstabcadefghijknlmnopst",
  accessKeyId: "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRST",
  sessionToken: "this is optional ==",
});
console.log(signedRequest);
var req = https.request(signedRequest, function (res) {
  var chunks = [];

  res.on("data", function (chunk) {
    chunks.push(chunk);
  });

  res.on("end", function (chunk) {
    var body = Buffer.concat(chunks);
    console.log(body.toString());
  });

  res.on("error", function (error) {
    console.error(error);
  });
});
req.write(postData);
req.end();
```

since this call is made from lambda whole object with keys can be skipped and simply call `aws4.sign(options)`, it should use from environment variables.