# AWS Elasticsearch generate api-key

Tags: elasticsearch, amazon-iam, aws-cdk, api-key, aws-elasticsearch

I've created an elasticsearch service in AWS using AWS CDK.
Originally I thought of accessing it using IAM, but the way to do it in node is [horrible](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticsearch-service/latest/developerguide/es-request-signing.html#es-request-signing-node), so I turned to auth through api-key.

If I follow the [elasticsearch docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/security-api-create-api-key.html), I get the following error:
`AuthenticationException(401, '{"Message":"Your request: \'/_security/api_key\' is not allowed."}')`

I assume this is due to my default user not having the right permissions to access the `_security` API, but then how can I create said api-key?

Comment: I don't think x-pack is supported in AWS ElasticSerach. try [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-aws-es) library , makes it very easy to send signed requests to elastic

Comment: unfortunately that library is designed for a soon to be deprecated elasticsearch client. You're right, the _security API is not supported by AWS elasticsearch.

Comment: [Here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@acuris/aws-es-connection) is another library. In general there is no workaround to sending signed requests , whether its Api Gateway , RDS or another AWS service to use IAM Auth. at first it looks crazy but signing is pretty straight forward, once we get used to.

Comment: Thank you man, this one actually works. It's a temporary solution anyway since I'll need to expose this service to a third party who cannot authenticate via IAM, I think I'll host elasticearch on EKS to get access to the full service, including the _security API. If you care to elaborate your comments into an answer I'll gladly accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From comments:

Security API is part of x-pack which is not support yet by AWS Elasticserach service. if we need to use it with in AWS, using it as SAAS from [AWS MarketPlace](https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/B01N6YCISK?qid=1500412556212) is an option. However, there are other options to secure AWS Elasticsearch:

- Using cognito to secure elastic, gives fine grained controls for users with identity pools and iam roles. [Here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticsearch-service/latest/developerguide/es-cognito-auth.html) are some details.
- IP based [Resource polices](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticsearch-service/latest/developerguide/es-ac.html#es-ac-types-ip). As long as clients are within network AWS/non-AWS, "*" principal with conditions restrict to cidr range. Anyone can access, no fine grained access for users within same ip cidr range.
- IAM Authentication: Gives fine grained control, needs AWS credentials via role(could be separate cognito too) or user cred, to sign the http requests with v4 signature. if we manually sign the http request, we can use [aws4-sign](https://github.com/yugasun/aws4-sign), We just need to pass, service, region and body to `aws4.sign` method options in addition to nodejs http request options. Similar to example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66702315/10186808) with service as `es`. Couple of libraries which wraps this signing for elastic are [aws-es-connection](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@acuris/aws-es-connection) and [http-aws-es](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-aws-es)